# How to properly remove an event listener?

Tags: events, actionscript, listener

I've got a few event listeners than i need to able to remove once they are no longer needed.
I've followed the advice of a few others and included the RemoveEventListener inside the function itself like:

```
        object1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, function StartMove(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            mousePoint = new Point(MC.mouseX, MC.mouseY);
            objectOffset = new Point(int(mousePoint.x - object1.x), int(mousePoint.y - object1.y));
            mousePoint.y -= objectOffset.y;
            mousePoint.x -= objectOffset.x;
            mousePressed = true;
            event.currentTarget.removeEventListener(event.type, StartMove);
        });
```

but this simply creates the listener and then deletes it when its used once.
The event listener functions are created inside a larger function (MouseMoves()) as they make use of local variables within MouseMoves(). (not sure whether this is an appropriate way to do this.)
So if i try to remove the listeners externally they cant see the function name to remove, and i cant declare the functions outside MouseMoves() cus they use variables inside it.

feel like this is bad design on my part but i'm not sure where?

is there a 'proper' more standard way to remove an event listener?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you ready to have you event listener removed you could use the same syntax that you used to add it in the first place. So somewhere in your code when you're ready to remove this listener you could have this

```
object1.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, function StartMove(event:MouseEvent):void
```

This way your being specific about which object you want to remove the listener from.
Your mouse function would look like this:

```
object1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, function StartMove(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            mousePoint = new Point(MC.mouseX, MC.mouseY);
            objectOffset = new Point(int(mousePoint.x - object1.x), int(mousePoint.y - object1.y));
            mousePoint.y -= objectOffset.y;
            mousePoint.x -= objectOffset.x;
            mousePressed = true;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your coding of:

```
event.currentTarget.removeEventListener(event.type, StartMove);
```

can be used without problem in the StartMove function. It is just to unregister the event in the listener, don't worry if it is in the event function. And of course you can also use:

```
object1.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, StartMove);
```

in the StartMove function as well if you do not want to use event.currentTarget.removeEventListener.